# Por que o EntityManager não possui o método createQuery com retorno tipado?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

Estou seguindo o projeto do livro Spring-MVC da Casa Do Código, usando a última versão do Hibernate, a 4.0.3.

Porém em um momento, quando o livro indicava a criação de uma query tipada 
através do seguinte código:

```
// manager é um objeto da classe javax.persistence.EntityManager
manager.createQuery("minha query", MinhaEntidade.class);
```

Eu notei que o meu objeto `EntityManager` respondia á assinatura apenas de um método chamado `createQuery`, onde o único parâmetro aceito é uma `String`, e não mais uma classe como segundo parâmetro.

Contudo, alguem sabe me informar se este método não é mais usado, se é algum erro meu ou o que pode estar diferente do projeto do livro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este método existe no Java EE 7 (que tem a JPA 2.1):

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createQuery-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-

No Java EE 6 (que tem a JPA 2.0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class)

Mas não no Java EE 5 (que tem a JPA 1.0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html

Vendo o [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/TypedQuery.html) da interface `TypedQuery`, que é o tipo de retorno do método que você quer:

> Since:
>   Java Persistence 2.0

Ou seja, se este método não apareceu para você é porque você provavelmente está com um JAR para usar a JPA 1.0, e não a JPA 2.0 ou 2.1.

Você pode baixar o último JAR para usar a JPA 2.0 (Java EE 6) no hibernate aqui:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api/1.0.1.Final

Ou então para a JPA 2.1 (Java EE 7):

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final

Comment: Na mosca, muito obrigado